# Restoring Scale Symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scale-invariance, scaling

To comprehend more about Scale Symmetry.. I need to know what it would take to restore Scale Symmetry that would make mass and length vanish. For example.. to restore Electroweak symmetry breaking.. you need to have the Higgs vev turn into zero... so to restore Scale Symmetry. what do you need to do? There is less descriptions about this than the Higgs and EWSB.

Reference:

https://www.quantamagazine.org/to-avoid-the-multiverse-physicists-propose-a-symmetry-of-scales-20140818/

Comment: There isn't any confirmed model on how the breaking the conformal/scale invariance should be involved. There are two mass scales in the standard models of particle physics and general relativity: the Higgs tachyonic mass, $\mu$, and the Planck mass, $M_p$ (equivalently inverse of sqrt of Newton's constant), respectively. To obtain a conformal theory, you need to get rid of those masses by some kind of symmetry breaking mechanisms. See for example scalar-tensor theories of gravity for the latter one.

Comment: Isn't a scalar field involved such as the gravity higgs that can put dimensionfull values to the planck scale (something about dimensional transmutation) hence breaking the scale invariance? Bottom line is. Isn't new scalar field is what breaks the scale invariance?

Comment: Yes, hence the name, *scalar*-tensor theories of gravity. Of course if you are working on a supersymmetric theory, the breaking should be due to a **super field** (a multiplet of scalar and a fermion, or a fermion and a vector boson). In that case the symmetry is called Kähler symmetry.

Comment: For the weak scale conformal/scale invariance breaking.. should there be a separate scalar-tensor theories of the weak that breaks the scale symmetry of the weak or should it all be due only to scalar-tensor theories of gravity (or planck scale) that should affect the weak scale too?